# (Integer's max value + 1) + (Integer's max value + 1) = 0?

Tags: theory

Basically, an integer's max value is 2147483647 and the min value is -2147483648, which makes when you add 1 to the max value of integer, it becomes to the min value of integer.

If I put the max value of int(I use 'max' as below):

```
(max+1) + (max+1)
```

the result is 0.

Apparently the plus sign reverse into minus. Why? What is the theory behind this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you already understand the topic of integer overflow/underflow, let's look at the math.

For the sake of argument let's just say that the minimum integer is -8 and the maximum is 7.  Therefore we would get the following reduction:

```
given (max + 1) + (max + 1) using integer overflow/underflow
= (7 + 1) + (7 + 1)
= (-8) + (-8)
= -8 + -1 + -7
= 7 + -7
= 0
```

When you add -1 to -8 you are actually subtracting 1 from -8 giving you a result of -9.  Because this is an underflow the answer becomes 7.  So when you subtract 7 from 7 you get 0.

If we looked at it in binary using twos' complement, it looks something like this:

```
given (max + 1) + (max + 1) using integer overflow/underflow
= (0111 + 0001) + (0111 + 0001)
= (1000) + (1000)
= 1000 + 1111 + 1001
= 0111 + 1001
= 0000
```

The binary math really depends on how you're storing the sign of the integer.  Like I said, we are using twos' compliment here, but there are other methods like ones' compliment, and Excess-K.

Comment: Can I treat it like a line to look at it?
Like this: 2147483647|-2147483648|-2147483647

if I use -2147483648 + 1 it becomes to 2147483648 and if you add -2147483648 which you are doing is using -2147483648 moving forward 2147483648 times so the result is 0?

Comment: -2147483648 + 1 is equal to -2147483647, not 2147483648.  Even then, the max integer is not 2147483648, but rather 2147483647.

Comment: typo :) it shold be -2147483648 - 1 = 2147483647

Comment: I believe the one liner would be (-2147483648) + (-1) + (-2147483647) = 0.  So yes, you are correct.

Comment: Can you explain more? What is the flow behind ? How the binary works?

Comment: I have updated my answer.  Is this a school assignment?

Comment: No I'm not a student anymore :( I just wanna make my concept of coding better

Comment: I recommend also reading the Wikipedia article on the subject of how signed integers are stored in a binary format: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations

Answer (score 3):

Suppose int is 32-bit 2's complement, then

```
max = 2³¹-1
```

and `max + 1 = 2³¹` (or -2<sup>31</sup> if you use wrap-around signed arithmetic)

Therefore

> (max + 1) + (max + 1) = 2 × 2<sup>31</sup> = 2<sup>32</sup>

which has **all low 32 bits zero**. If you're doing a non-widening addition (like how additions are done in high-level languages) then the bottom 32 bits will be truncated, resulting in zero

In other words, it's the result modulo 2<sup>32</sup> equals zero